# Logistic regression: How can I penalize false positives different than false negatives during training?

Tags: logistic, gradient-descent, regularization

I developed a simple fraud detection example to test logistic regression. I have `n` features (e.g. credit score, account balance, etc.), `m` samples for training and I try to compute my output `y` with `0 - fraud` or `1 - no fraud`. Everything works well so far.

As next step, I would like to penalize the misclassification. It isn't great, but not the end of the world, that the classifier computes `0` and the actual result is `1`. However, the case `1 - no fraud` calculated and training output was `0` should be penalized higher than the other case (real world: costs of not detecting fraud is higher than blocking a good customers credit card).

I assume I have to adjust my gradient function to change my theta's more in one case or the other. Is that right? Or do I need to adjust my cost function?

I am using this cost function below

```
J(θ) = (1/m) * Sum(−y(i)*log(hθ(x(i))) − (1 − y(i))*log(1 − hθ(x(i))))
```

and this standard gradient descent approach

```
∂J(θ)/∂θ = (1/m) * Sum((hθ(x(i)) − y(i)) * x(i))
```

Can anybody recommend some literature how such a penalty would be applied?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you take a look at Frank Harrell's answer and consider moving your check to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of the logistic model is a calibrated probability (not a classification or pseudo-probability as produced by many machine learning algorithms) - thus you can change the cost simply by changing the probability cut-off used for classification. So instead of using the default 50% probability cut-off you can try any cut-off 0-100% probability.

- It is often worth checking model calibration using a test set
- if you want to explore this visually, you can use the AUC curve and a family of cost lines. The gradient of the cost lines = (1-p)CFP/pCFN with p=prevalence. So if fraud 1% of time, cost FP to FN 1:5 then gradient = 19.8. The optimal point is the point of the AUC where a line with this gradient forms a tangent with curve. Relatively low prob cut-off with low sensitivity and high specificity
- In practice usually use crossvalidation or test data to optimize probability cut-point to a given ratio of FP/FN (I think there is a formula to derive this cut-point but can never find it when I'm looking for it)

Answer (score 3):

I don't feel is is appropriate to change the coefficients away from the maximum likelihood estimates.  These provide optimal estimates of $\beta$ that yield optimal estimates $\hat{P}(Y=1 | X=x)$.  Once you verify the calibration of your model you can set up any decision function and study its characteristics.  The optimal Bayes decision is that which maximizes expected utility/minimizes expected cost.  The cost/utility/loss function is defined separately from the model.  You can translate this to an action threshold for $\hat{P}$ that yields a subject-specific cutoff for $\hat{P}$.

Comment: I strongly recommend that the questioner uncheck the checked answer and check this one.